# What are the request limits on background location in Android 11+ in a foreground service (FLP)?

Tags: android, geolocation, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation, fusedlocationproviderclient

Our Android app starts a foreground service that is guaranteed to be foregrounded by the user before use. However, we now need to get user location even when the user has backgrounded the app or locked the phone or something. If the app has been foregrounded but then the activity is backgrounded/destroyed/phone locked in this session, what are the limits on background location?

The Android docs say at most a few requests per hour, but I've just tested it and I'm still receiving location even every 1-2 seconds just fine. What's the actual limitation? Does it take a long time for these limitations to kick in? To me, it seems background location is 100% the exact solution I need.

EDIT: Tested with a physical device in normal state, no doze mode or low battery or anything.

Comment: Unclear how you tested, i.e. did test with a physical device and/or with [doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby)?

Comment: Tested with a physical device in normal state, no doze mode or low battery or anything.

Comment: A running `ForegroundService` will get as many location updates as the phone can provide. There's no limitation, since it has a persistent status bar icon and the user knows it's running.